Conectar script de pyhton con html en wordpress
vengo con una consulta sobre como conectar un script de python a html el cual es este:
import csv

 # Lee los datos del archivo CSV 
with open(r"archivo.csv, 'r') as archivo_csv:
lector_csv = csv.reader(archivo_csv)
datos = list(lector_csv)

# Solicita al usuario que ingrese el nombre de la carrera
nombre_carrera = input("Ingresa el nombre de la carrera: ")

# Busca la columna "Carrera" en los encabezados
encabezados = datos[0]
indice_carrera = encabezados.index("Carrera")

# Filtra los datos según el nombre de la carrera
datos_filtrados = [fila for fila in datos if fila[indice_carrera] == nombre_carrera]

# Verifica si hay datos para crear la tabla
if datos_filtrados:
# Encuentra las coordenadas de la celda inferior derecha
fila_inicial = datos.index(datos_filtrados[0])
fila_final = min(fila_inicial + 18, len(datos) - 1)
columna_final = min(len(fila) - 1 for fila in datos_filtrados)

# Crea la tabla HTML
tabla_html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Carrera</th>
            <th>Hora</th>
            <th>Lunes</th>
            <th>Martes</th>
            <th>Miércoles</th>
            <th>Jueves</th>
            <th>Viernes</th>
            <th>Sabado</th>
        </tr>
"""

# Agrega filas a la tabla con los datos filtrados (sin espacios vacíos)
for fila in datos[fila_inicial:fila_final + 1]:
    # Verifica si hay datos en la columna "Hora"
    if fila[1].strip() and any(celda.strip() for celda in fila[2:]):
        tabla_html += "<tr>"
        for celda in fila[:columna_final + 1]:
            # Convierte el valor a cadena (str)
            celda_str = str(celda).strip()
            tabla_html += f"<td>{celda_str}</td>"
        tabla_html += "</tr>"

# Cierra la tabla y el documento HTML
tabla_html += """
    </table>
</body>
</html>
"""

# Guarda el contenido en un archivo HTML 
with open('horario.html', 'w') as archivo_html:
    archivo_html.write(tabla_html)

print("Archivo HTML generado correctamente.")
else:
print(f"No se encontraron datos para la carrera '{nombre_carrera}'.")

El código genera un archivo .html con los datos de un archivo csv, sin embargo lo que quiero hacer es tener una tabla prehecha en html y realizar una peticion que ejecute dicho script y solo me vacie los datos a la tabla ya hecha. Estoy utilizando wordpress y no encuentro algun plugin que me pueda ayudar y tampoco se sobre bases de datos.
De antemano muchas gracias

no has considerado en mejor usar [tag:django]?

No entiendo, dices que ... lo que quiero hacer es tener una tabla prehecha en html y realizar una peticion que ejecute dicho script y solo me vacie los datos a la tabla.. y ese script que tienes no hace justamente eso???

No me expliqué bien, lo siento. A lo que me refería era a tener una tabla ya hecha en una pagina web y que el script solo llene los datos de acuerdo a la peticion que se ralice, el script si genera la tabla en un html, pero solo necesito los datos en una web con una tabla ya hecha. Una disculpa por no explicarlo bien

OK.. para lo que queres hacer, tenes que cambiar varias cosas.. primero, tu python deberia ser una API que devuelva datos.. ahora, no lo es... luego, debes poder aprender a llamar a esa api.. luego, debes poder manipular el dom de tu pagina para cargar los datos (en lo posible con ajax)... asi que ya tenes donde empezar a ver mil cosas que tenes que ahcer...

¿Estamos aquí ante un caso del problema XY? Sospecho que si...

@gbianchi Muchas gracias! Voy a investigar como hacer la api y como llamarla, ahora ya se por donde comenzar..
